# How to play soundcloud music in ios app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, soundcloud

I'm trying to play music from my profile in soundcloud, I downloaded sounCloud API project, but it looks very difficult, maybe exist easiest way? Help me please. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, did you end up getting anything to work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make a GET request for the track you're trying to play:

```
[api performMethod:@"GET" 
        onResource:@"tracks" 
    withParameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"12821506"  forKey:@"ids"] 
           context:context userInfo:nil];
```

You can then register a SCSoundCloudAPIDelegate and implement:

```
- (void)soundCloudAPI:(SCSoundCloudAPI *)soundCloudAPI 
    didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data 
              context:(id)context 
             userInfo:(id)userInfo;
```

If the context is equal to the context you passed in when making the GET request, you know your request is complete. You can build an NSDictionary modeling the response, and then grab the stream URL for streaming:

```
NSDictionary *trackInfo = [data objectFromJSONData];
NSString *steamURL = [trackInfo objectForKey:@"stream_url];
```

The full list of parameters you can specify when making the GET request is available [here](https://github.com/soundcloud/api/wiki/10.2-Resources%3a-tracks).

Comment: How do you instantiate the api object in the first method?